# How do I access Dock preferences?

Tags: plank

I changed the position of the dock to the left of the screen. I don't like it. I would like it back at the bottom as default. To do so we right-click on the dock to access its preferences but it is just not possible.

The dock does not have any space around or between icons where I may right-click. It is a great miscalculation on the part of elementary-design-team that they did not provision for some space around the dock where one could right click.

Is there any way I could get around to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
plank --preferences
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I also checked the box _Show Item for Dock_ found in the **Behaviour** tab. That way I wouldn't have to suffer so much if I could not remember the command.

Comment: The checkbox for _Show Item for Dock_ is not available in **Plank preferences** any more. However, there is still a convenient way to access **Plank preferences** - do a `CTRL + Click` anywhere on the plank. A menu will open with an entry for *Preferences*. Click on that.

Comment: It's `CTRL + RightClick` @HarshVardhan . But thanks